# STM32 CPU Usage during ISR

Tags: embedded, stm32, freertos, stm32f4, nucleo

I am using freertos on STM32F4-Nucleo. To get CPU usage I am using vTaskGetRunTimeStats() with following changes

```
**void configureTimerForRunTimeStats(void)
{
    g_osRuntimeCounter = 0;
}
unsigned long getRunTimeCounterValue(void)
{
return g_osRuntimeCounter;
}**
```

The g_osRuntimeCounter increments in timer callback function. Everything works fine I am getting CPU usage of running tasks and IDLE time but is there a way to get CPU usage in ISR?
The CAN reception and USB-OTG reception is interrupt based and executes few functions. And I need CPU usage of that.

Comment: Do you want to know how much time your app spends in the interrupts?

Comment: Quick and probably most exact Way: Set an interrupt high on ISR start and low on exit. Measure the time with oscilloscope.

Comment: Software solution: Get systick value on Interrupt Start and end, calculate dif and add it to a global variable.

Comment: Most complicated solution: If your controller has Tracing capabilities, use a trace debugger like Lauterbach or Segger J-Trace to measure the execution time of the ISR functions.

Comment: I think it's not supported by freertos, since it gets interrupted by ISRs. Another issue is that typical systick you have is slow, usually 1ms (you could set it of much higher frequency, but that could mess with interrupting everything else). I would set up freerunning timer, read that at the beginning and end of ISR, calculate the difference and add to total global value.